# Assign hash to array

Tags: arrays, ruby, file, hash

My goal is create a hash that stores values from an array as the keys and gets values from another array as the values. I would like to relate "i" value from one array to "i" value from another array.

My first array stores the name of files and second their sizes. I want to indicate some field from the name array and display its size

```
arr = []
arr_s = []
size = Hash.new
Dir.glob("#{dirname}/**/*") do |file|
  if File.file?(file)
    arr_s[i] = File.size(file)
    arr[i] = File.basename("#{file}")
    i += 1
    size["#{arr[i]}"] = "#{arr_s[i]}"
    puts size["#{arr[i]}"]
  end
end
```

Comment: var "i" is a counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
size = Hash[arr.zip(arr_s)]
```

To give you a better idea, in `irb`, I typed:

```
a = (1..5).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 

b = ('a'..'e').to_a
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Then, typing

```
size=Hash[a.zip(b)]
```

Returns

```
{1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c", 4=>"d", 5=>"e"}
```

So you could do:

```
puts size[1]
```

which would return

```
"a"
```

etc.

Comment: Fine, works but I would like to display only value of key instead of whole statement

Comment: no because in my case keys are not further numbers but name of files. It looks like : {"hey"=>7, "file1"=>23, "xxx.doc"=>6, "other"=>1002}.

Comment: Then you would do: `size["hey"], size["file1"]` etc.

Comment: sure it works but I need to do it using loop because then I want to select some of them

Comment: what do you mean when you say `you want to select some of them`?

Comment: I've done it in other way but now I dont know how to do that compare all elements in array and return that where the diffrence is less than for instance 3. Example arr = [1,10, 44, 2] will return 1 and 2

Comment: I thought about sort of array but I cant do it because further elements are related to other array (names)

Comment: I think we're moving off topic here. I'm fairly certain I answered your original question. Please mark the answer as accepted and post a new question if you're stuck on something different, which it seems like right now.